# How do I get the cell from a table layout panel vb.net

Tags: vb.net, tablelayoutpanel

How do I get which cell the user clicked if it has no control in the cell. What I really need is for an image to appear at the cell location when it's clicked but not in it.

I imagine it would be similar to this pseudo code

```
myimage.location = get.cellLocation()
```

or something. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your need for having a 'chess' style table that accepts clicking, I have created this. I didn't have a need for it, but I figured it would be a fun diversion. This example creates **63** cells, so it's very close to what you're wanting. Since it's calculated on the fly, you should be able to rework it for what you need.

First, your form will be set up with a `PictureBox` (easier to render without calculating margins and whatnot) named `picBoard`, another `PictureBox` called `picTile`, and then a `Label` named `lblDetails` docked at the bottom to act as a status bar. My `InitializeComponent` looks like this:

```cs
  private void InitializeComponent()
  {
     this.picBoard = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
     this.picTile = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
     this.lblDetails = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
     ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.picBoard)).BeginInit();
     ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.picTile)).BeginInit();
     this.SuspendLayout();
     // 
     // picBoard
     // 
     this.picBoard.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 21);
     this.picBoard.Name = "picBoard";
     this.picBoard.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(360, 280);
     this.picBoard.TabIndex = 0;
     this.picBoard.TabStop = false;
     // 
     // picTile
     // 
     this.picTile.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
     this.picTile.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(143, 67);
     this.picTile.Name = "picTile";
     this.picTile.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(51, 51);
     this.picTile.TabIndex = 1;
     this.picTile.TabStop = false;
     this.picTile.Visible = false;
     // 
     // lblDetails
     // 
     this.lblDetails.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
     this.lblDetails.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Bottom;
     this.lblDetails.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 326);
     this.lblDetails.Name = "lblDetails";
     this.lblDetails.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(393, 23);
     this.lblDetails.TabIndex = 2;
     this.lblDetails.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
     // 
     // Form1
     // 
     this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
     this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
     this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(393, 349);
     this.Controls.Add(this.lblDetails);
     this.Controls.Add(this.picTile);
     this.Controls.Add(this.picBoard);
     this.Name = "Form1";
     this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
     this.Text = "Grid Test";
     ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.picBoard)).EndInit();
     ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.picTile)).EndInit();
     this.ResumeLayout(false);

  }
```

Here is the entirety of the `Form` code, as well as a custom class, `CellDetails`, at the bottom (I didn't feel like making a separate one). Keep in mind this is just something I created in a hurry to see how difficult it would be for you. If you have any questions as to what is going on, just ask.

```cs
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {

      List<CellDetails> cells = new List<CellDetails>();
      // Defines the size of each cell.
      const int cCellSize = 40;
      int boardLeft = 0;
      int boardTop = 0;
      public Form1()
      {
         InitializeComponent();

         picTile.Size = new Size(cCellSize, cCellSize);

         picBoard.MouseMove += PicBoard_MouseMove;
         picBoard.MouseClick += PicBoard_MouseClick;
         picBoard.Paint += PicBoard_Paint;
         CreateCells();

         boardLeft = picBoard.Location.X;
         boardTop = picBoard.Location.Y;
      }

      private void PicBoard_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
      {
         if (cells.Count > 0)
         {
            bool alt = false;
            SolidBrush cellBrush1 = new SolidBrush(Color.LightGray);
            SolidBrush cellBrush2 = new SolidBrush(Color.DarkGray);

            foreach (CellDetails cell in cells)
            {
               e.Graphics.FillRectangle((alt ? cellBrush1 : cellBrush2), cell.Dimension);
               alt = !alt;
            }

            cellBrush1.Dispose();
            cellBrush2.Dispose();
         }
      }

      private void PicBoard_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
      {
         CellDetails cell = FindCell(e);
         if (cell != null && cell.Location.X > -1 && cell.Location.Y > -1)
         {
            picTile.Location = new Point(cell.Dimension.X + boardLeft, cell.Dimension.Y + boardTop);
            picTile.Visible = true;
         }
         else
         {
            picTile.Visible = false;
         }
      }

      private void PicBoard_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
      {
         CellDetails cell = FindCell(e);
         string details;

         if (cell == null || cell.Location.X < 0 || cell.Location.Y < 0)
         {
            details = "Could not find cell";
         } else
         {
            details = string.Format("Row: {0}, Col: {1}", cell.Location.Y, cell.Location.X);
         }
         lblDetails.Text = String.Format("{0}, {1} = {2}", e.X, e.Y, details);
      }

      private CellDetails FindCell(MouseEventArgs e)
      {
         CellDetails ret = null;
         foreach (CellDetails cell in cells)
         {
            if (cell.Dimension.Contains(e.Location))
            {
               ret = cell;
               break;
            }
         }
         return ret;
      }

      private void CreateCells()
      {
         CellDetails cell;
         Point cellLoc;
         int rows = (picBoard.ClientSize.Height / cCellSize);
         int cols = (picBoard.ClientSize.Width / cCellSize);

         // Loop through the rows
         for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
         {
            // Loop through the columns
            for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
            {
               cell = new CellDetails();
               cellLoc = new Point();
               cellLoc.Y = row + 1; 
               cellLoc.X = col + 1; 
               cell.Location = cellLoc;
               cell.Dimension = new Rectangle(col * cCellSize, row * cCellSize, cCellSize, cCellSize);
               cells.Add(cell);
            }
         }
         lblDetails.Text = String.Format("Generated {0} cells.", cells.Count);
      }

   }
   public class CellDetails
   {
      public CellDetails() { }
      public Rectangle Dimension { get; set; }
      public Point Location { get; set; }
   }
```

The end result looks something like this:

[image: Dynamic Grid Example]

If you know how many rows and columns you want, you can have it calculate the cell width/height by dividing up the `ClientSize` by the counts instead of by a predefined cell size. This would also be helpful if you can resize, which would result in a varying cell size. Just alter the code to calculate that way, and then have it call `CreateCells` after resizing. You'll probably want to add a line like `if (cells.Count > 0) cells.Clear();` at the top, too.

It probably doesn't need mentioning, but in case someone else comes along: If you just need hit testing for invisible cells (no rendering), you can completely remove the `Paint` event. If you are wanting grid lines and not filled boxes, change `FilledRectangle` to `DrawRectangle`, and use a `Pen` instead of `SolidBrush`. With the `Pen`, you can also make lines dotted, dashed, etc.

Comment: It's one of those days. I wrote this whole thing in C# instead of VB.NET. You should be able to convert it to VB.NET fairly easily, though.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there isn't an actual "cell" container collection. The cells are dynamic based on the `ColumnCount` and `RowCount`, along with the corresponding `ColumnStyles` and `RowStyles`.

If your styles are using fixed sizes, you can write your own method to calculate and store the details of each cell -- probably in a struct or class containing a `Rectangle` for each cell (location would be calculated, and the size could be retrieved from the paired `ColumnStyle` and `RowStyle`) and a `Point` or 2 `int` for storing column and row. Then, in the `MouseClick` event of the `TableLayoutPanel`, you can use the `e.Location` and check it against all of the cell Rectangles using `Rectangle.Contains`. Then, use the `SetCellPosition` method of the `TableLayoutPanel` to move the control around. For example:

```
tableLayoutPanel1.SetCellPosition(pictureBox1, new TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(1, 1));
```

If any of your columns or rows have dynamic sizing (percentage, etc), then you'll have to do more work to calculate the details of each one.

If the positioning can change, you'll need to redo the calculations. Therefore, you would want to make sure each set of calculations is done inside of a method that can be called from Resize events, etc.

If you don't want to go through all of this craziness, there are a couple of other things you can do (and maybe more, but these are just off the top of my head):

1. Put the same control type, such as `PictureBox`, into each cell. When one is clicked, set the image to that of your source control. When another is clicked, clear out the previous one and then set the new one.
2. Do some control swapping magic by putting any type of control, such as a `Label`, into each cell. When one is clicked, remove it from the cell and put your image control into it. When another one is clicked, remove it, put the image control in its place, and then put the first removed control back in the original cell.

I would think the first option would be the easiest. But, the final approach is up to you.

Comment: Hm, I thought about the first option but I would have to have  80 controls and to me that's really more effort than it's worth. the second one more or less presents the same problem. Is there an alternative to a 'chess' style table?

Comment: You can "draw" it in memory using `Rectangle` and such and use the mouse coordinates in `Contains`. You would be clicking on a blank form, but recognizing individual "cell" locations. That's why finding a chess example would be good (coordinate tracking, etc).

Comment: I created a second answer with a lot of details on what I was talking about for "in memory" cell tracking.